# What does (Conditional probability = 1) imply

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

What does $p(A|B)=1$ (or equivalently $p(A∩B)=p(B)$) imply?

I guess it leads to $p(B⊆A)=1$ but I couldn't prove it. Is it right? If not, give a counter example.

Comment: Can you come up with an example where it does work?

Comment: What you mean under $P(B \subset A)$?

Comment: @zkutch I mean it happens almost surely and if it's not true, the measure of that part of $B$ that is not contained in $A$ is zero.

Comment: I am not asking about $P(B)=1$ type expression, but about $P(B \subset A)$ itself. Am I clear now?

Comment: The answer is what you've said in your last comment.  $\Pr(B\setminus A)=0$

Comment: It means the probability of B and not A is 0. B doesn’t have to be a subset of A, since there can be zero probability events in B and not A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression
$$
p(B⊆A) 
$$
does not make sense, so you can't prove it.

Probability is a function whose domain consists of subsets of the sample space, extended to the expressions that define conditional probability, not relations between those subsets. So all you can say is the equivalent statement
$$
p(A∩B)=p(B) \ .
$$

The *idea* you are trying to express is correct. Knowing that an event in $B$ occurred, you know that an event in $A$ occurred. That means that $B$ must be a subset of $A$, up to probability. In a finite sample space, it must be an actual subset (assuming individual elements have nonzero probability). In the continuous case it can happen that  $A - A\cap B$ is nonempty but has probability $0$.

Comment: What do you mean by "$A - A\cup B$ is nonempty"? I think it will be always empty 

Comment: I fixed the typo, changing $\cup$ to $\cap$.

Comment: Yeah. I mean up to probability. But how can I write it? I think I must use some measure theory. Mustn't I?

Comment: There's nothing to write. You have already noted that $p(A \cap B) = p(B)$. It follows from the fact that probabilities add for disjoint sets that $p(B \  \backslash A) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$1=\Pr(A|B)=\frac{\Pr(A\cap B}{\Pr(A\cap B)+\Pr(B\setminus A)}$$ so that $\Pr(B\setminus A)=0$.

As a concrete example, let the probability space be $[0,1]$ with the uniform distribution, and let $A=(0,1],\ B=[0,1)$.